# Refresh access token ember

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

My app access token expires every 10 minutes. I'm using ember simple auth for authentication, but is a custom authenticator, because I have more than just username and password fields. I wanted to use ember-simple-auth-token, but calling to authorization:jwt in my adapter, it doesn't work, apparently is because I'm not using it's authenticator.

So, I was considering to use a service that renew the token every ten minutes, something like this http://www.davekerr.co/programming/2015/05/17/add-a-polling-service-to-your-ember-app/, so my question is how to overwrite the sessionData token.

My custom authorizer file code looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/base';
export default Base.extend({
    authorize(sessionData, block) {
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(sessionData.token)) {
          block('Authorization',  'Bearer '+sessionData.token);
          block('Content-Type',  'application/json');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do that in your custom authenticator as the authenticator is responsible for acquiring and managing tokens and authentication state in general. You can simply schedule a timer that updates the token some time after initial authentication. Once the token has been refreshed the authenticator can trigger the [`sessionDataUpdated` event](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/BaseAuthenticator.html#event_sessionDataUpdated) that the session will automatically handle.

Check the [implementation of the OAuth2PasswortGrantAuthenticator](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/1.1.0-beta.3/addon/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant.js) for an example of how to update tokens from the authenticator.